# MongoDB: Sort on an array and return the same document multiple times in the cursor

Tags: mongodb

Say I have a collection that has these documents in it:

```
{sort:[1,2,4,6], fruit:'apple'}
{sort:[3], fruit:'cherry'}
{sort:[5], fruit:'orange'}
```

And I want to run a query similar to this:

```
 db.collection.find().sort({sort: -1})
```

But have it return the documents without dedupeing them first like this:

```
{sort:[1,2,4,6], fruit:'apple'}
{sort:[1,2,4,6], fruit:'apple'}
{sort:[3], fruit:'cherry'}
{sort:[1,2,4,6], fruit:'apple'}
{sort:[5], fruit:'orange'}
{sort:[1,2,4,6], fruit:'apple'}
```

Instead of this:

```
{sort:[1,2,4,6], fruit:'apple'}
{sort:[3], fruit:'cherry'}
{sort:[5], fruit:'orange'}
```

Is there any way to achieve this in the current MongoDB?

Comment: Is there something like the opposite of snapshot mode? http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/snapshot/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the aggregation framework's [$unwind operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind) to unwind an array into multiple documents.

```
db.fruits.aggregate(
  {$unwind: "$sort"},
  {$sort: {sort: 1}}
)
```

The `$unwind` operation "unwinds" an array on a document by creating multiple documents, one for each value in that array. Then, we just sort on the criteria given. So for the inputs:

```
> db.fruits.insert({sort:[1,2,4,6], fruit:'apple'})
> db.fruits.insert({sort:[3], fruit:'cherry'})
> db.fruits.insert({sort:[5], fruit:'orange'})
```

We get the resulting output:

```
> db.fruits.aggregate({$unwind: "$sort"}, {$sort: {sort: 1}})
{
  "result" : [
    {
      "_id" : ObjectId("51f0592c8a542caf3f07fa66"),
      "sort" : 1,
      "fruit" : "apple"
    },
    {
      "_id" : ObjectId("51f0592c8a542caf3f07fa66"),
      "sort" : 2,
      "fruit" : "apple"
    },
    {
      "_id" : ObjectId("51f059358a542caf3f07fa67"),
      "sort" : 3,
      "fruit" : "cherry"
    },
    {
      "_id" : ObjectId("51f0592c8a542caf3f07fa66"),
      "sort" : 4,
      "fruit" : "apple"
    },  
    {
      "_id" : ObjectId("51f0593b8a542caf3f07fa68"),
      "sort" : 5,
      "fruit" : "orange"
    },
    {
      "_id" : ObjectId("51f0592c8a542caf3f07fa66"),
      "sort" : 6,
      "fruit" : "apple"
    }
  ],
  "ok" : 1
}
```

If you need to maintain the original sort array, you can use `$project` to create a projection of the original document that copies the sort field into an `expanded_sort` field, which is then unwound, like so:

```
db.fruits.aggregate(
  {$project: {sort: 1, fruit: 1, expanded_sort: "$sort"}},
  {$unwind: "$expanded_sort"},
  {$sort: {expanded_sort: 1}}
)
```

This gets you results like so:

```
"result" : [
  {
    "_id" : ObjectId("51f0592c8a542caf3f07fa66"),
    "sort" : [ 1, 2, 4, 6 ],
    "fruit" : "apple",
    "expanded_sort" : 1
  },
```

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted! Thank you for taking the time.